# json dataType is not working in jquery ajax method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

i'm just trying to query the database and display the result the jquery's ajax method but if i put the dataType property as json it is only logging the result which has only one object the following is my code:

```
//this is a method is an object which will be triggered after a selection was made
lister: function () {
    //this is to target the object as it is inside an event
    var self = users;
    //the ajax call
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: self.config.form.serialize(),
        //this is the dataType    
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (results) {
            //this for logging the result
            console.log(results);
        }
    });
}
```

the php code

```
if(isset($_POST['q']) && !empty($_POST['q'])){
    $na = $_POST['q'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id,first_name, last_name 
                          FROM users WHERE users.first_name LIKE '$na%'");

    $num=mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($num >= 1){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            //encoding the result as json
            echo json_encode($row); 
        }
     } else{
        echo "no results found ";
     }

     //here we return so it won't display all of the pages
     return;
}
```

Comment: please format code so it is readable with proper indent and minimal whitespace...rather ridiculous to have to scroll to read about 10 lines of code

Comment: @charlietfl scroll to read 5 lines of code actually. `:]`

Comment: Proper indentation is important too!

Comment: @facebook-100005867078573  and did a poor job...I cleaned up the js...try clenaing up your php

Answer (score 1):

You are generating invalid JSON. You are encoding every row of your table independently, which generates something like this:

```
{"foo": "bar"}{"foo": "bar"}{"foo": "bar"}
```

This is isn't valid. It's just a concatenation of objects. What you need is an *array of objects*:

```
[{"foo": "bar"}, {"foo": "bar"}, {"foo": "bar"}]
```

You can achieve that by creating an array first, add each row to it and encode the array:

```
$data = array();
while(...) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Another problem is that in case no results are found, you are simple returning plain text, not JSON. This will probably result in an error on the client side. If you tell jQuery to expect JSON, then every possible response must be JSON. So you might want something like:

```
echo json_encode(array('error' => 'no results found'));
```

or even better, return an empty array:

```
echo json_encode(array());
```

It should be fairly obvious to the client that no results have been found if an empty array is returned.

Comment: should i want to do the echo outside the loop ??